Is there a way to show show the original 'anchor'/position of an element which is shifted via float?
Is ist possible to show the XXX via a css trick without using an additional html element or container? I tried using pseudo elements and translate but it didn't work.


p {
background-color: grey;
max-width: 200px;}

small {
float: right;
margin-right: -120px;
width: 100px;
}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <mark>XXX</mark> <small>This is a sidenote</small>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>




I’m afraid I’m not clear what is required. I see the side note at the side and the XXX highlighted. What exactly does ‘show the XXX’ mean?

You could do it the other way round. The small being the marker and a pseudo element being the side note text.
However, you may need to consider accessibility.


p {
background-color: grey;
max-width: 200px;}

small {
  background: yellow;
}
small::before {
  content: 'This is a side note ';
  float: right;
  margin-right: -120px;
  width: 100px;
}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <small>XXX</small>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>



